# LWC - NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl promise returns JavaScript:void(0)

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate, setter

In my component, I have an api setter method for recordId and I am generating a URL based on the given recordId inside the setter. I am storing the generated URL and using it as href value like this `<a href={recordPageUrl}>...</a>`.

The component is inherited from

```
... extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api
    set recordId(value) {
        this._recordId = value;
        
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: '0050R00000AVZsgQAH',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        }).then((url) => {
            this.recordPageUrl = url;
            console.log(url)
        });
    }
```

The promise is returning  **JavaScript:void(0)** instead of URL. I tried to remove the setter and move `this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({...})` to `connectedCallback` then it is working fine and the promise is returning a valid URL.

I have looked into the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) of PageReference Types and I am not missing any required attribute. On the other hand, salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) is always using the **GenerateUrl** inside the **connectedCallback**.

Summary: Any idea why **NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl** is not working inside the setter?

Comment: Are you using the url in an <a> tag or do you need to open the page with a event handler?

Comment: yes I am using the url in the href and I don't have any handler attached to the `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do this. One way is to still use the connectedCallback, but make it async and do the following. Also, remove the setter for recordId. This is a bit cleaner.

```
async connectedCallback() {
    this.recordPageUrl = await this.getUrl();
}

getUrl() {
    return this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    });
}
```

You can also use a getter for the recordPageUrl as well and remove the setter again for the recordId.

```
_recordPageUrl;

get recordPageUrl() {
    this.getUrl().then((url) => {
        this._recordPageUrl = url;
    });
    return this._recordPageUrl;
}

getUrl() {
    return this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            actionName: "view"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In your example, you already have the recordId available but in my case, my component is executing some async code to get a recordId and then I am calling the setter of the child component and passing the recordId.

Comment: The record Id would be a public api property in my example. If you need to call a method on your child component create a public function. The public function can also be an async function.

Comment: yes, I can make it work like that but back to the question, why it's not working inside the setter? if the setter is working then I don't need to add any additional method to the component except setter.

Comment: What's the issue then? I tested both methods above using a parent component passing the record Id into child and the url will be set in each scenario. Why would we need to set the url in a recordId setter? That's not the general use case for a setter. The issue is that navigation mixin returns a promise, so you either need a getter or use the connected callback.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, wrapping your call to the `NavigationMixin` in a `setTimeout` resolves this issue. I have to imagine this is the result of some amount of spaghetti in the LWC engine.

```js
... extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api
    set recordId(value) {
        this._recordId = value;
        
        window.setTimeout(() => this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: '0050R00000AVZsgQAH',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        }).then((url) => {
            this.recordPageUrl = url;
            console.log(url)
        }), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. To me `setTimeOut(..)` seems like a workaround and we might have to save the `timeoutID()` and then add another line to call the `clearTimeOut()` afterward.